# Dog years equivalent to human years coding python

Tags: python

I've tried doing coding for dog years but not sure what's wrong & don't want to overcomplicate it. These are the instructions:

> Write a program that converts that age
> of a dog to the equivalent age for a human. The program uses the following
> method:
>
> The user inputs the age of the dog in years.
>
> - If the age is 2 or less, the human equivalent is 12 times the age.
> - If the age is more than 2, the human equivalent is 24 for the first
>   2 years plus 6 for every additional year.
>   Output the dog years and the human equivalent
>
> Use the table below for testing
>
> | Dog Age | Human Age |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 12 |
> | 2 | 24 |
> | 3 | 30 |
> | 4 | 36 |
> | 5 | 42 |

Also attached is a link to what I mean.[https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaZqw.png]

[image]

Comment: Please include your code in your post.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. This is one of the first things you should learn about Python.

Comment: As per [ask], your post must not rely on external links, and you especially need to include your code _as **text**_, not as an image.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on asking a question that best enables the community to help you.  Please note [it is generally not acceptable to post an image of your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/6831341) -- instead, please post it as text in the body of your question.  Also, you may be helped by [this post about how to best ask homework questions on the site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Please read about [if-elif-else in python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp), about [indentation in python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) and about [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is with your indentation, and more importantly, the way you used the if-else statement. Code below will give you insight into the process of using the if-else statement in your problem:

```py
ageDog = int(input("What is the dog's age? "))
if ageDog <= 2:
  ageHuman = ageDog * 12
else:
  ageHuman = 24 + 6 * (ageDog - 2)
print("Human's age is " + str(ageHuman))
```

##### Samples output

```
What is the dog's age? 1
Human's age is 12
```

```
What is the dog's age? 4
Human's age is 36
```

Comment: Variable names in python should be in [snake case](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#type-variable-names). In addition, arithmetic operations should be separated by a space. Other than that, seems like a good solution.

Comment: @EyalGolan Thanks for the note, Eyal. Since I started programming with PHP, camelCase coding has been stuck with me. I will try coding in snake case in my future scripts. Thanks!